# Why doesn't the module "sys" work in Programiz online compiler

Tags: python

I'm not sure if its outdated or not but, when I try to run `import sys` on [Programiz's online compiler](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/), it displays

> A module you have imported isn't available at the moment. It will be available soon.

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: The depends on what "online compiler" you are taking about.

Comment: Which "online complier"?  I'm guessing it's disabled deliberately; there might be documentation explaining why.

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/ sorry for not clarifying

Comment: It looks like they only support modules fully implemented in Python.  The basic reason is "that's the way it is".  There are lots of other choices for online interpreters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reasons might be the following -

Python is a powerful language, and to enable it on an online editor, the providers have to work to create a safe environment. Sometimes this safe environment is known as sandbox environment.

Why is that required?

To restrict access to the backend systems, private configurations, hiding information about the infrastructures/technologies used.

To create this environment, providers restrict some functionalities of these languages (not necessarily python) which can be used by the end users to breach the systems.

There can be other reasons as well.